# Client Side Encryption Security of key

Tags: security, authentication, encryption

This may sound a bit naive but I am missing something and I want someone to enlighten me.

To prevent man in the middle attacks where your password in plain text could be easily read, client Side Encryption is done where the password is encrypted so a man in the middle can only find data which is gibberish for him. However, for the encryption, the server needs to send a key over the network.

So, my question is, if a man in the middle attack occurs, then he would be able to see the key as well which was sent for the encryption on the client side. With the key in his possession, the encrypted password can be very easily decrypted. Hence, the whole purpose of the encryption is defeated.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a precision: the attack you are talking about is not a MITM but passive eavesdropping.  In a MITM, the attacker relays back and forth messages from the two parties.

Sending a symmetric key along with the encrypted data would of course be silly as an eavesdropper would sniff it as well as the data.  This is why **asymmetric encryption** (aka **public key encryption**) is used.

In asymmetric cryptography, ciphers do not operate with a single key but with a key pair, composed of a public key and a private key.  Public and private key are created together at the same time using a special algorithm and they are strictly connected to each other. The client encrypts the data with the server's public key, which is the only key that is shared publicly; this data can only be decrypted by the server with the server's private key.  The communication from the server to the client is done in the same way.

You might want to read about PKC here:

- https://enigmail.wiki/Introduction_to_Cryptography,_PGP,_and_Enigmail
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

It is worth noting that a MITM attack can actually happen at the moment one of the parties shares his public key with the other:

> First, Alice asks Bob for his public key. If Bob sends his public key to Alice, but Mallory is able to intercept it, a man-in-the-middle attack can begin. Mallory sends a forged message to Alice that claims to be from Bob, but instead includes Mallory's public key.
> Alice, believing this public key to be Bob's, encrypts her message with Mallory's key and sends the enciphered message back to Bob. Mallory again intercepts, deciphers the message using her private key, possibly alters it if she wants, and re-enciphers it using the public key Bob originally sent to Alice. When Bob receives the newly enciphered message, he believes it came from Alice. [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

This is actually the weak point of PKC; the solution is either to use a centralized Certificate Authority (this is how it is done for the SSL certificates used in HTTPS), or use a shared Web of Trust. Both solutions have their advantages and drawbacks.

Comment: In telecommunication, there is a thing called Frequency Hopping, where different data packets are sent at different frequencies, making it difficult signals to be interrupted. Obviously we cannot have that in computer networks. But, what if, there is a way, to send the data across different networks, so that if there is a passive evesdropper or MITM attack, they would only have partial data. Assuming, the server is in USA and I am in Europe, there are several cables connecting the 2 continents and the packets can be sent through different cables. Is something like this done or feasible?

Comment: That's a completely new question. But the simple answer is no: the sequence of "frequencies" *is* the password/encryption key.

Comment: This is infeasible as you'd need a completely separate physical circuit between the server in USA and your machine in EU -- including in the transoceanic backbone.